# Negative lookahead to match words not in list

Tags: python, regex, nlp, data-preprocessing

Need some help coming up with the right regex! I have a list of words, and essentially want to match any words (including alphabet, number, special characters, etc. since I'm planning to clean the text I match) that are NOT in the list.

Example list of words: `["chip_n_dale", "86", "fast_&_furious", "apple", "b&w", "abc_123"]`

Example input text:

```
heres some example text to convert to &cleaned te3'xt & 8 86 is a number and fast_&_furious is a show what about chip_n_dale those are carto0n_ cha_racters not b&w dont know about abc_123 5nonalpha apple
```

Example of what parts of the text should be matched:

```
heres some example text to convert to &cleaned te3'xt & 8 is a number and is a show what about those are carto0n_ cha_racters not dont know about 5nonalpha
```

To solve this, I'm trying to use negative lookahead, but each of my attempts seem to encounter a different problem.

1. `phrases_re = re.compile(r"\b(?!(" + '|'.join(re.escape(w) for w in phrase_list) + r")\b)\w+")`

This gives me the result closest to what I need. But underscored words containing special characters aren't matched properly. For instance, `'fast_&_furious'` yields a match of `'_furious'`. I'm guessing this is probably because `'fast_&_furious'` is not consumed in negative lookahead, and the underscore is not captured by `'\w+'`. Unfortunately I'm stuck on how to capture the entire word instead of assuming `'_furious'` is part of a separate word.

Same problem for `'b&w'`: `'w'` still gets matched.

2. phrases_re = re.compile(rf'\b(?!:{"|".join(map(re.escape, phrase_list))})\b')

This is strangely matching the spots between characters. For convenience, using `'^'` to mark what parts get matched:

> fast_^&^_furious^ chip_n_dale^ b^&^w^

3. `phrases_re = re.compile(r'(?<!\S)(?!:{})(?!\S)'.format("|".join(map(re.escape, phrase_list))))`

In this case, only the spots between spaces or new lines get matched. For instance, using `'^'` to mark what parts get matched:

> chip_n_dale
> twenty
> ^
> ten tea ^ b&w ^ ^ ^

EDIT:

- expect that the text the regex is being applied to has already been partially processed (changed to lowercase, hyphens replaced by whitespace, all punctuation except ampersands removed)
- Also I want to match anything (other than whitespaces, which I handle removing later by calling `.split` on the text) in the text that is not exactly something in my list of words.
- So this text:

> An Apple, apple, apples, apple-tree with an apple and a dapple
> "apple"'

Would actually come as:

> an apple apple apples apple tree with an apple and a dapple apple

And regex would match:

> an apples tree with an and a dapple

- Note that I'm doing this because my end goal is to only clean words not in my list. In other words, take the matched (non-list) words, call a processing function on them, and then replace the matched words in the original text with the cleaned matched words. I call re.sub using the `phrases_re` regex pattern like so (assume `post_phrase_tokenize_processing` just removes any remaining numbers/punctuation):

```
content = phrases_re.sub(lambda m: post_phrase_tokenize_processing(m.group()), content)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'words' in this context? If `'apple'` is in the phrase list and you apply it to `'An Apple, apple, apples, apple-tree with an apple and a dapple "apple"'`, what exactly do you expect to remain?

Comment: `fast_&_furious` cannot match your text because this is not the same as `fast_&furious (missing "_"). Typo?

Comment: Why `carto0n` become `carto0n_`? Typo?

Comment: sorry formatting issues, the underscore automatically italicizes :( Fixed and also added clarification about words!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub` which is more logic if you want to remove text:

```
text = """heres some example text to convert to &cleaned te3'xt & 8 86 is a number and fast_&_furious is a show what about chip_n_dale those are carto0n_ cha_racters not b&w dont know about abc_123 5nonalpha apple"""

sol = """heres some example text to convert to &cleaned te3'xt & 8 is a number and is a show what about those are carto0n_ cha_racters not dont know about 5nonalpha"""

phrase_list = ["chip_n_dale", "86", "fast_&_furious", "apple", "b&w", "abc_123"]
phrases_re = re.compile(fr"\b\s*({'|'.join(re.escape(w) for w in phrase_list)})\b")

clean = re.sub(phrases_re, '', text)
```

```
>>> clean == sol
True

>>> clean
"heres some example text to convert to &cleaned te3'xt & 8 is a number and is a show what about those are carto0n_ cha_racters not dont know about 5nonalpha"
```

Comment: Ah edited question above to include this but the reason I'm doing this is because I only want to clean words not in my list, i.e. take the matched words, call a processing function on them, and then replace the matched words in the original text with the cleaned matched words. Do you know how I could do this (match anything not in my list)?